# Issue to offset lastrow

Tags: excel, vba, offset

I have a problem to offset from the previous row my last row. Indeed I try to run my code below, I have the error message which appears

> compile error: invalid qualifier…

The problem apparently comes from my variable `lastRow4 = lastRow3.Offset(-1, 0)`

When I remove this line of my code and I replaced in my VBA code the penultimate line `Range("A3:F" & lastRow4).Select` by `Range("A3:F" & lastRow3).Select`, my code works but the selection selects my range until `lastrow` (in my code, it is `lastRow3`) and it is not what I want.

If someone knows the solution how to fix the issue in order that my variable lastRow4 does not return me any error message, that would be great.

Many thanks in advance.
Xavi

```
Sub gdfgdhgf()


Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer, lastRow3 As Integer, lastRow4 As Integer
Dim currentRowValue As String

sourceCol = 5 'column F has a value of 5
rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row 'for every row, find the first blank cell and select it
For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
    currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
    If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then
        lastRow3 = currentRow
    End If
Next
lastRow4 = lastRow3.Offset(-1, 0)
Range("A3:F" & lastRow4).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You received the error because `lastRow3` is an integer not a range, so you can't use `Offset`

Comment: ^^ that. Now with that said, row numbers/counts should be `As Long` (32-bit), not `As Integer` (16-bit). Any value greater than 32,767 will overflow an `Integer` (runtime error 6).

Comment: In essence, that line should just be `lastRow4 = lastRow3 - 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below is not the code. it is an example. modify and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '<- Get the last row of column A sheet1

        'In order to refer to line before Lastrow you can use:

        .Range ("A" & LastRow - 1)

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you for your help! The reply which helps me the most to fix my issue was the one of Error 1004, I modified the code he provided (please see below) and it works perfectly now:  Sub test () Dim LastRow As Long

  

      LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '<- Get the last row of column F 

        'In order to refer to line before Lastrow you can use:

        Range("A3:F" & LastRow - 1).Select

   

End Sub

Answer (score 3):

Try the code below, explanation inside the Code's comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub gdfgdhgf()

Dim sourceCol As Long, rowCount As Long, currentRow As Long, lastRow3 As Long, lastRow4 As Long
Dim CurrentRng As Range
Dim currentRowValue As String
Dim Sht As Worksheet

Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name

sourceCol = 5 'column F has a value of 5

With Sht
    rowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row ' for every row, find the first blank cell and select it

    For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
        ' I think you are trying to set it as a range
        Set CurrentRng = .Cells(currentRow, sourceCol)

        If IsEmpty(CurrentRng) Or CurrentRng.Value2 = "" Then
            lastRow3 = CurrentRng.Row ' get the row of the CurrentRng.Row
        End If
    Next

    lastRow4 = lastRow3 - 1 ' just subtract 1, no need to use Offset
    .Range("A3:F" & lastRow4).Select ' <-- Not sure why you need to Select
End With

End Sub
```